\tl_gset_rescan with \c_str_cctab inserts unwanted tokens into resulting token list
For a package that is supposed to parse JSON, I need to read in an argument verbatim that may contain line breaks as string with some special attributes. After a recent update of my LaTeX installation, my package throws an error as soon as there are line breaks in the argument.
I could track down the issue to the following MWE. The point is that if there is a line break in the argument of the command \JSONParse, the tokens \OT1\obeyedline (or similar) are somehow inserted into the resulting token list where the line break was in the original string. This, however, breaks the following parsing of this token list.
Check the output in the log, it shows { "a" :\OT1\o beyedline "b" }, but it should actually show { "a" : "b" }. Where do these two tokens come from and how can I prevent them from showing up?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { jsonparse } { debug-info } {
    #1
}

\tl_new:N \g__jsonparse_json_tl

\cctab_const:Nn \c__jsonparse_json_escape_cctab {
    \cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab
    \char_set_catcode_escape:n { 92 }
    \bool_lazy_or:nnF
        { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: } { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
        { \int_step_function:nnN { 128 } { 255 } \char_set_catcode_active:n }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \JSONParse } { +v } {
    \group_begin:
        \tl_gset_rescan:Nne \g__jsonparse_json_tl { 
            \cctab_select:N \c__jsonparse_json_escape_cctab 
        } {#1} 
        \msg_log:nne { jsonparse } { debug-info } {
            \g__jsonparse_json_tl
        } 
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \JSONParse{ { "a" : 
            "b" } }
\end{document}


oh you are rescanning in \c_str_cctab so \obeyedline is \o beyedline as the \o is catcode 12 so you only get a single letter csname. but why rescan?

Why rescan? Well, this is the full context: https://github.com/jasperhabicht/jsonparse/blob/main/jsonparse.sty ... I essentially want single-letter csnames here. Thanks for the hint! This makes things much clearer!

I just found this answer which explains that the implementation of the +v argument has changed as of recently and EOLs are now tokenized as \obeyedline which is obviously the reason for this token being inserted in the above token list.
The solution is to locally redefine \obeyedline:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { jsonparse } { debug-info } {
    #1
}

\tl_new:N \g__jsonparse_json_tl

\cctab_const:Nn \c__jsonparse_json_escape_cctab {
    \cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab
    \char_set_catcode_escape:n { 92 }
    \bool_lazy_or:nnF
        { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: } { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
        { \int_step_function:nnN { 128 } { 255 } \char_set_catcode_active:n }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \JSONParse } { +v } {
    \group_begin:
        \tl_set:Nn \obeyedline { ~ }
        \tl_gset_rescan:Nne \g__jsonparse_json_tl { 
            \cctab_select:N \c__jsonparse_json_escape_cctab 
        } {#1} 
        \msg_log:nne { jsonparse } { debug-info } {
            \g__jsonparse_json_tl
        } 
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \JSONParse{ { "a" : 
            "b" } }
\end{document}

Output to log is now { "a" : "b" }.
